# What's the correct way to assign PAnsiChar to a (unicode-) string?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2, delphi-2007, pchar

I have got a DLL function that returns a pointer to ANSI text (PAnsiChar). I want to assign this to a (unicode-) string (This is Delphi XE2.). The following compiles but I get a warning
"W1057 Implicit String cast from 'AnsiChar' to 'string'":

```
function TProj4.pj_strerrno(_ErrorCode: Integer): string;
var
  Err: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Err := Fpj_strerrno(_ErrorCode);
  Result := Err;
end;
```

EDIT: The text in question is an error message in English, so there are unlikely to be any conversion problems here.

I am now tempted to just explicitly typecast Err to string like this ...

```
Result := String(Err);
```

.. to get rid of the warning. Could this go wrong? Should I rather use a temporary AnsiString variable instead?

```
var
  s: AnsiString;
[...]
s := Err;
Result := String(s);
```

If yes, why?

Or should I make it explicit, that the code first converts a PAnsiChar to AnsiString and then the AnsiString to a String?

```
Result := String(AnsiString(Err));
```

And of course I could make it a function:

```
function PAnsicharToString(_a: PAnsiChar): string;
begin
   // one of the above conversion codes goes here
end;
```

All these options compile, but will they work? And what's the best practice here?

Bonus points: The code should ideally compile and work with Delphi 2007 and newer versions as well.

Comment: You need to know the code page used to encode the 8 bit text. Unless you know that you can't hope to make progress.

Comment: The text in this case is an error message in English, so it's unlikely to cause any issues.

Comment: So, how is the text encoded? Which code page? Do you know? If you are happy with "unlikely" then why do you want to know best practice?

Comment: I guess that @dummzeuch is trying to say that the text is plain ASCII, so unlikely to contain any inconvertible items, regardless of codepage. But we all know that Turkish EBCDIC (CP 1026) is not compatible with ASCII-7. <g>

Answer (score 5):

If the text is encoded in the users current locale then I'd say it is simplest to write:

```
var
  p: PAnsiChar;
  str: string;
....
str := string(p);
```

Otherwise if you wish to convert from a specific code page to a Unicode string then you would use `UnicodeFromLocaleChars`.

Comment: Hm, yes. I don't know the code page, because there is not much documentation on the dll at all. I'd assume Windows-1252 because that's what's most widely used by people who don't care about Unicode. So, i'll probably just use a single typecast as you suggest.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The type cast will use the current code page which may not be 1252. And it would be unusual for a library to give you text in a fixed code page. More likely would be that the text is either ASCII or encoded in the current code page. Either way the simple cast would be fine. My guess is that if the library does not state a code page, then the text is encoded in the current code page.

Comment: Actually if it's US-ASCII it may not be compatible with the current code page. For example I just learned that code page 1026 (IBM EBCDIC Turkish Latin-5) is not US-ASCII compatible.

Comment: It's in the Code Page Identifiers list on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx

Comment: @Asbjørn Yes, but then so is 65001 and you can't have that as your ANSI code page. As I understand it, all ANSI code pages contain ASCII.

Comment: @David: try `chcp 65001` on a Windows command line. Works fine. You can also have TEncoding with 65001 (which is the same as TEncoding.UTF8) and an AnsiString with 65001 as codepage (which is the same as UTF8String).

Comment: @Rudy Yes I know that UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII.

Comment: @Rudy Are you asserting that, for instance, GetWindowTextA can return UTF-8 data? That would be news to me.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis By your reckoning I can use `chcp` to arrange that this program `program Project43;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  s: AnsiString;

begin
  Writeln(StringCodePage(s));
end.` outputs 65001. Is that what you are claiming?

Answer (score 3):

I think the **general** solution is assigning c char pointer to RawByteString, then set its codepage corresponding to c null-terminated string encoding.

```
var
  bys :TBytes;
  rbstr :RawByteString;
  ustr :string;
  pastr :PAnsiChar;
begin

  SetLength(bys,5);
  bys[0] := $ca;
  bys[1] := $e9;
  bys[2] := $d2;
  bys[3] := $b5;
  bys[4] := 0;

  pastr := @bys[0]; // just simulate char* returned by c api


  rbstr := pastr; // assign PAnsiChar to RawByteString
  // assume text encoded as codepage 936
  // Note here: set 3rd param to false!
  SetCodePage(rbstr,936,false);

  ustr := string(rbstr);
  ShowMessage(ustr);
end;
```

And the other cross-platform solution is (vcl,fmx,fmx with mobile platform)

```
function CString2TBytes(ptr :{$IFDEF NEXTGEN} MarshaledAString {$ELSE} PAnsiChar {$ENDIF}) :TBytes;
var
  pby :PByte;
  len :Integer;
begin
  pby := PByte(ptr);
  while pby^<>0 do Inc(pby);
  len := pby - ptr;
  SetLength(Result,len);
  if len>0 then Move(ptr^,Result[0],len);
end;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bys, cbys: TBytes;
  ustr: string;
  // PAnsiChar is undefined in mobile platform
  // remap param foo(outSting:PAnsiString) => foo(outString:MarshaledAString)
  ptr: {$IFDEF NEXTGEN} MarshaledAString {$ELSE} PAnsiChar {$ENDIF}; //
  encoding : TEncoding;
begin

  SetLength(bys, 5);
  bys[0] := $CA;
  bys[1] := $E9;
  bys[2] := $D2;
  bys[3] := $B5;
  bys[4] := 0;

  ptr := @bys[0]; // just simulate char* returned by c api

  cbys := CString2TBytes(ptr);

  // assume text encoded as codepage 936
  encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(936);
  try
    ustr := encoding.GetString(cbys);
    ShowMessage(ustr);
  finally
    encoding.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: For mobile, you can use `MarshaledAString` instead of `Pointer`. Also, `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` returns a new object that must be `Free`'d on desktop platforms. And you cannot type-cast a plain `PAnsiChar`/`Pointer` to a `TBytes` and expect it to work correctly, a dynamic array has extra metadata that a plain pointer does not have, and `TEncoding.GetString()` uses that metadata (in particular, the array length). So you will have to allocate memory for the `TBytes` and copy the `ptr` data into it. Or use Delphi's marshaling API to allocate a buffer that the DLL can write to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for comment. According to what you concerned, I just modifed mobile part to be more robust. With "try finally free" block let the compiler to deal with ARC/Non-ARC.  About Pointer to TBytes, I did not find any read-made cross-platform function to calculate its length, so I create it.  If anyone knows any read-made function in delphi, please let me know. Thanks.  Mobile part was tested in XE and XE7.

Comment: I don't understand why there is so much complexity here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, it can be very simple if codepage is the same as caller env and AnsiString can be used.
Of course, UnicodeFromLocaleChars should work fine, but IMO its parameters are complex and easy to make mistake to me.
Just an alternative way. :)

Comment: UFLC isn't hard. Bear in mind that your code had mistakes to begin with.